# Is there any facility available for separation of production deployments vs test deployments with the same server of gocd?

Tags: testing, deployment, devops, cicd, go-cd

1. Any way to add test deployment facility on same server
2. Also how can we do with other server

I don't have idea about this. Please suggest solution if anyone worked on this previously. Also what are possible problems will anyone face while doing this.